# How to randomly sample small rotations?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I need a random rotation matrix that rotates random vectors by $\approx \arccos 0.9$

- `RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[n]]` gives rotation matrices that are unrestricted
- Orthogonalizing `IdentityMatrix[n] + small_noise` gives a small rotation, but for larger $n$, this gives a large rotation even for small amount of noise.

Any tips?

Below is a heuristic attempt which adjusts amount of noise until arccos[0.9] target is hit, but it's too slow to run for $n=1000$

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
randn[i_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], i];
randn[i_, j_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {i, j}];

(*Generate rotation matrix by orthogonalizing Identity with eps \
perturbation*)
epsRotation[n_, eps_] := 
  Module[{M, z, q, r, d, ph, indices}, 
   z = IdentityMatrix[n] + eps   randn[n, n];
   {q, r} = QRDecomposition[z];
   d = Diagonal[r];
   ph = d/Abs[d];
   M = q*ph;
   (*determinant may be -1 corresponding to reflection,
   switch 2 rows of the matrix to guarantee true rotation*)
   indices = If[Det[M] > 0, Range[n], {2, 1}~Join~Range[3, n]];
   M[[indices]]
   ];

(* Finds eps such that average rotation is about arccos(0.9) *)
On[Assert];
getEps[d_] := Module[{},
   x0 = {1}~Join~ConstantArray[0, d - 1];
   target = 0.9;
   {epsHist, cosHist} = {{}, {}};
   eps = 0.001;
   For[i = 1, i < 1000, i += 1,
    cos = First[x0 . epsRotation[d, eps]];
    If[cos < target, eps *= 0.9, eps *= 1.1];
    AppendTo[epsHist, eps];
    AppendTo[cosHist, cos];];
   Assert[0.5 < Mean[cosHist[[-500 ;;]]] < 0.95];
   Mean[epsHist[[-500 ;;]]]
   ];

With[{d = 100},
 mat = epsRotation[d, getEps[d]];
 vec = randn[d];
 angle = vec . mat . vec/Norm[vec]^2;
 Print["rotation angle cos: ", angle]
 ]
```

Comment: Would filtering out vectors from `RandomPoint[Sphere[1000], 5000]` help? `vecs = RandomPoint[Sphere[1000], 10000]; // AbsoluteTiming` is very fast.

Comment: In high dimensions almost all vectors are orthogonal to each other

Comment: Yeah... `Select[vecs, # . v == 0.9 &]` returns an empty list for `v = {1,0,0,...,0}` and the max dot product I got was 0.125... so it seems rejection sampling won't work :(

Comment: Wouldn't this work? `With[{n = 3}, RotationMatrix[ArcCos[0.9], RandomPoint[Sphere[n], 2]]]` Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding from what kind of underlying distribution you want to sample ...

Comment: @Domen I'm looking to sample of subset of `CircularRealMatrixDistribution` which represent rotation matrices. `RotationMatrix` is a "simple rotation", and general rotation matrices correspond to combinations of simple rotations (ie, yaw+pitch+roll)

Comment: @Domen Your method makes sense, but even for $n=3$ we have `(m . v) . v` != 0.9 and $n=1000$ is way off. I'm not sure where it goes wrong but it could be numerical error in `RotationMatrix`.

Comment: Related?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197772/generalized-rotation-matrix-in-n-dimensional-space-around-n-2-unit-vector.

Comment: @jimb hat's simple rotation which leaves poles unchanged. Mathematica has function to rotate around arbitrary axis. I'm looking for general rotation that touches every vector

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your comment, but every rotation has an axis (and points on the axis will be unchanged).

Comment: @mikado  rotation matrix like what you get out of RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[n]] can be viewed as a combination of simple rotations. I'm looking for subset of that random set

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use spherical linear interpolation here in conjunction with `RandomPoint[Sphere[n]]`?

```
slerpAngle[v1_, v2_, a_] := 
 With[{Ω = ArcCos[v1 . v2]}, 
  With[{t = 
     a/Ω}, (Sin[(1 - t) Ω]  v1 + 
      Sin[t  Ω] v2)/Sin[Ω]]]

n = 1000;
v0 = SparseArray[1 -> 1, n]; (* your vector to rotate *)
test = slerpAngle[v0, RandomPoint[Sphere[n]], ArcCos[0.9]];
test . v0 (* 0.9 *)
```

If you aren't dealing with normalized vectors, then just record the norm, slerp the normalized vector, and then multiply by the original norm at the end.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov any opinions on this approach?